# Dereferencing pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I just managed to write a global CBT hook in c++, usable with c#.
It may sound stupid but my knowledge of pointers and dereferencing of those is very bad due to my work with c#.

I'm not able to dereference a pointer inside a struct pointed to by the lParam.

It looks like this: the lParam is a long Pointer to a CBT_CREATEWND struct, which in turn holds a member "lpcs", and a pointer to a CREATESTRUCT. This struct contains a member "x", which I want to read. I tried the following, but I get invalid values for x:

```
CREATESTRUCT str = *(LPCREATESTRUCT)(((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs);
int normal = str.x;
PostMessage(FindWindow(NULL, L"Process Watcher Window"), RegisterWindowMessage(L"ALEXX_SEINE_WNDMESSAGE_C"), wParam, normal);
```

could someone please help me?

Comment: Dereferencing part looks fine. are you sure that you called api functions correctly to get values?

Comment: Can you not do this: LPCREATESTRUCT str = (LPCREATESTRUCT)(((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs); followed by int normal = str->x;

Comment: @Michael : (LPCREATESTRUCT) cast is not needed. `lpcs` is already of type `LPCREATESTRUCT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems to check out, even though it is perhaps a bit unreadable, and the `LPCREATESTRUCT` cast is obviously unnecessary.

You mentioned that you get invalid values for `x`, perhaps `lParam` is not really a pointer to a `CBT_CREATEWND` structure? Are you checking that `nCode` of the callback function is equal to `HCBT_CREATEWND` before casting `lParam`?

Comment: So what values are you getting for `x`? Is the value invalid but always the same? Can you give examples? I suppose I am sort of making this into a Win32 question rather than about pointers, but it's clear this is not a dereferencing issue.

Comment: OK, for expample I get -2147483648 (or something similar) every time a window is created!

Comment: `#define CW_USEDEFAULT 0x80000000`, which is -2147483648 when the type is LPARAM (long, 32-bit). The value is correct, and your code is fine. Reference `CreateWindowEx` documentation on parameter `x`.

Comment: what does "usedefault" mean? so I should read the lParam in c# as an UIntPtr? but then I have CW_USEDEFAULT, but what is the window position then??

Comment: Open a bunch of explorer windows, without moving any of them. They are automatically positioned by the system because they were initialized with `CW_USEDEFAULT` as the x/y parameter of `CreateWindowEx`. If you need to retrieve the positioning of a window, you can do it later on in your program, after `ALEXX_SEINE_WNDMESSAGE_C` message has been processed.

Comment: but I want to position the window _initally_ on the left side outside the desktop, so I set the "x" member to -cx, but the window still remains where it was! How can I get the position where the window should be, before it is being shown??

Comment: According to your original post, you are dereferencing the pointer to the structure. Firstly you should do as Evan Teran suggested and maintain a **pointer** to the structure. Then you can do something like `str->x = -str->cx;`. If this doesn't work, you can use `SetWindowPos` using the `HWND` that you grab in the hook.

Comment: ok, thanks. One last question: I want to reposition the window where it was supposed to be after a couple of seconds, but how can I know where to put it, when its X value was 0x80000000?

Comment: I've never known how exactly `CreateWindowEx` with `CW_USEDEFAULT` works, but you can try using `GetWindowRect` after the window is completely initialized. Then `SetWindowPos` to set the position to what you want... then `SetWindowPos` again after the delay. I'll update you here if I find out a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks very much, Skyler. Do you know how I could run GetWindowRect *immediately* after the window is initialized, so it does not pop-up on the screen and then vanish?

Comment: Why does the window vanish in the first place? Anyway, you might be able use your hook to handle `HCBT_MOVESIZE`, which should be sent right after `HCBT_CREATEWND`.

Comment: Hmm, thats a good idea, i could just wait for a HCBT_MOVESIZE to be raised with my window handle. I'll test it out. again, thanks for your help and pacience with me :)

Comment: Absolutely. Take care and feel free to post here if you need further help.

Comment: I have a problem: After calling the HCBT_CREATEWND hook, windows does not call a HCBT_MOVESIZE hook! What should I do now? Maybe set a Timer with 10ms interval to get the position with `GetWindowRect`

Comment: One last suggestion I have is try hooking at `HCBT_ACTIVATE`... Perhaps that will work. It doesn't seem like there's a good way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, `HCBT_ACTIVATE` does in deed fire immediately after `HCBT_CREATEWND`, and with `GetWindowRect` I can get the windows initial position! Thank you very much, Skyler.

Answer (score 3):

Well I can't really speak towards the fine details of why you get invalid x values, but I would likely write this code differently:

```
// the way you had it, it was making a copy of the CREATESTRUCT and storing it in str
// this just uses a pointer
LPCREATESTRUCT str = ((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs;
// when you have a pointer, use -> to use a member
int normal = str->x;
```

Since you said you are new to pointers, I'll explain `->` a bit. When you write `x->y`, it is really the same as `(*x).y` but with nicer syntax.

Also a note of advice, while the casts in this code seem reasonable. In general, if you find that you are casting a lot, you probably are doing it either the hard way, or the wrong way. So make sure you take the time to understand any casts that you do.

Comment: See my edits. Maybe the last line causes a wrong value being sent to my c# program?

Comment: Is the HWND you are trying to get info about in another process or something?